# probability of stock movement based on multiple technical indicators

Tags: probability

If a technical indicator can correctly predict a rise in a stock with probability P1 and another technical indicator can predict a rise in the same stock with probability P2 what would be the probability that the stock will rise if they both predict a rise?

would this be calculated using Bayes or would it be 1 - (both predict fall)?

Comment: What do you think? Why?

Comment: I can't be sure if the probabilities are dependent or independent. They are derived from the same data, so they should be dependent but they can be calculated by different operations on the data. I could be totally off and the answer might be more complicated than just Bayes, I would appreciate a pointer to the direction that I should look into if this is the case.

Comment: You'd first have to define what you mean by "correctly predict a rise in a stock with probability $p$".

Comment: say for example the moving average 50 has crossed the moving average 200 today and assume that for this indicator this is the indication that the stock will rise. Based on past performance N out of X times this has proven to be the case. So the probability of a correct prediction is N / X. This is what I mean by that.

Comment: @dendiz $1 - P(\text{"both predict fall"})$ is the probability that **at least one** indicator predicts a rise of the stock. You still have to apply Bayes to calculate the (conditional) probabiliy that the stock will rise if at least one indicator predicts a rise of the stock.